# How move SailsJS app from root folder to a sub-directory?

Tags: node.js, apache, sails.js

As I want to expose my sails application from behind an Apache server, I need ti move the app from / to /subfolder in order to male the proxypass direttive Workshop without any additional rewrite.

What’s the best way to do it?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: if you are using a unix like operating system you can use this command to move all the files. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/how-do-you-move-all-files-including-hidden-from-one-directory-to-another

Comment: Thanks skellertor, but your solution si not applicable to my case as the application si not directly exposed via Apache but trough a proxy that point to Another application server.